# $skip in mongodb aggregate query is not working

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

This is my query, and this is returning all the entries, not skipping the records.
Is there anything wrong in the query.

```
db.loan.aggregate([
                                            {"$skip": 6},
                                            {"$unwind": "$lenders"}, 
                                            {"$match": {"lenders._id": ObjectId("625fccde94a1917b85ac890")}},
                                            {"$lookup": {from: "portfolio", localField: "lenders.portfolio_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "Portfolio"}}  
                                        ]).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

In aggregate, `$limit` limits the number of documents sent to the next aggregation state, and `$skip` skips the first `N` documents. Try this:

```
db.loan.aggregate([
                    {"$limit": 6},
                    {"$unwind": "$lenders"}, 
                    {"$match": {"lenders._id": ObjectId("625fccde94a1917b85ac890")}},
                    {"$lookup": {from: "portfolio", localField: "lenders.portfolio_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "Portfolio"}}  
                 ]).toArray();
```

Or this:

```
db.loan.aggregate([
                   {"$unwind": "$lenders"}, 
                   {"$match": {"lenders._id": ObjectId("625fccde94a1917b85ac890")}},
                   {"$lookup": {from: "portfolio", localField: "lenders.portfolio_id", foreignField: "_id", as: "Portfolio"}},
                   {"$limit": 6}  
                     ]).toArray();
```

Comment: CW answer because [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73330172/revisions) was posted as spam, and then later edited by another user into a decent answer. Credit to [Charchit Kapoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12368154/charchit-kapoor).